# io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/plugin/JSONFormatter

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cucumber

if i remove the plugin key from the testrunner it work perfectly , but i need all those plugin to generate report like jenkins cucumber report  and i have attached the console message with all details ,please let me know how to fix since i ma beginner to it

below is the POM file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>14.0.1</version>
</dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.monochromata.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>reporting-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.56</version> <!-- this version can be bumped if we also upgrade our Cucumber dependency 
                versions -->
        </dependency>
```

**My test runner file**

```
package testRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/Features/", plugin = { "json:target/jsonReports/cucumber-report.json",
        "pretty", "html:target/html-report/cucumber-html-reports", "junit:target/xml-report/cucumber-xml-reports",
        "de.monochromata.cucumber.report.PrettyReports:target/pretty-cucumber" }, glue = {
                "StepDefination" }, tags = "@LogOut1wwww1", monochrome = true)
public class TestRunner {

}
```

and the project structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgCku.png)

below is the console error message Console message from eclipse

```
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/plugin/JSONFormatter
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.PluginFactory.newInstance(PluginFactory.java:118)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.PluginFactory.instantiate(PluginFactory.java:97)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.PluginFactory.create(PluginFactory.java:62)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.Plugins.createPlugins(Plugins.java:32)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:25)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:161)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/plugin/JSONFormatter
    at de.monochromata.cucumber.report.PrettyReports.createJsonEventListener(PrettyReports.java:58)
    at de.monochromata.cucumber.report.PrettyReports.<init>(PrettyReports.java:39)
    at de.monochromata.cucumber.report.PrettyReports.<init>(PrettyReports.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at io.cucumber.core.plugin.PluginFactory.newInstance(PluginFactory.java:114)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.core.plugin.JSONFormatter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: It says in your code" this version can be bumped if we also upgrade our Cucumber dependency versions". Might be a hint.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje no actually i need that dependency to generate a report in my local machine as it gives result while running in jenkins

Comment: I tired to figure out it , it was due to this plugin 
```
"de.monochromata.cucumber.report.PrettyReports:target/pretty-cucumber"
```

can any tell how to use this plugin report in this testRunner so that i can get report as i expect or any other plugin which i can get result like Jenkins one